# Why don't web browsers expose their time zone databases to the web pages?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, safari, timezone

It seems silly to me that web application developers to create a time zone picker have to load [the same list of time zones](https://www.iana.org/time-zones) the browsers already have, which can be quite large. Why don't web browsers just expose their lists to web developers via a JavaScript API?

Comment: Hi.  The place to bring this up would be the [TC 39 Temporal proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-temporal).  It has been brought up before in [issue #167](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-temporal/issues/167) and as part of [issue #103](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-temporal/issues/103). You could add your voice there, or open a new issue.  (However, this question is off-topic for Stack Overflow.)  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. What is temporal?

Comment: An English word, meaning in this case "relating to time". The TC39 temporal proposal is focused on improvements to date and time APIs in JavaScript.